# Pass parent as a parameter into child's synthetic event

Tags: reactjs, svg

```
Class MakeRotate extends React.Component {
  rectMOuseDown = (e, /* want the parent g here*/) => {
    /* I have to do some operation on g inside this function */
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <g className="some-class" transform="translate(40,40) rotate(0, 240, 80)">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" onMOuseDown={e => 
            this.rectMOuseDown(e, /*wana to pass parent g*/)}>
         </g>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I do not want to use the ref concept. Because in my code g is producing in loop. so can't assign same ref to all g. Is there any concept in react so that I can pass the whole g in is child's synthetic event function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Javascript `currentEvent` and go from there?
For example 
`onMouseDown={e => console.log(e.currentTarget.parentNode)}`

Or do you have a different use case?